# xamarin forms shadow blur

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to do a shadow on frame element with blur on android and IOS, I've implemented this [approach](https://alexdunn.org/2018/06/06/xamarin-tip-dynamic-elevation-frames/) but it has no effect on android.

the property "HasShadow" has no effect on android too.

how can I do a workaround to accomplish this ?

Comment: Are you getting expected results on iOS? Can you post your code for the XAML, the renderers, and any forms types you subclassed for this? I note that the custom renderer code is not complete in that blog post, hence why you should always provide the code you are using so we can see if you made the necessary additions to he code in the article, e.g. did you export your renderers (export attribute not shown in article's code for renderers)? If not, then they will not have any affect on any platform.

Comment: PS, I do see that "HasShadow" is having no, or very negligible, effect on Android.But you can see even in the docs, the shadow is. by default, very different on Android and iOS, with Android being much less pronounced to the point of barely being a visible shadow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/layouts#frame

Answer (score 1):

`HasShadow` is working on my end on Android, it is just a very small, bottom only shadow by default, but it is there for me.

That said, The code in the article you linked is working on my end, so I suspect what I said earlier is true, that you need to export the renderers for Android and iOS.

You need to add the following above the namespace declaration in the `MaterialFrameRenderer_Android.cs` and `MaterialFrameRenderer_iOS.cs` files, e.g.:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MaterialFrame), typeof(MaterialFrameRenderer))]
namespace ... 
{ 
    ...
}
```

The author assumed you have made custom renderers before by following these docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/